# Соответствие между dict.key() и dict.values()

Tags: python, словари

Насколько я понимаю, из-за того, что словари словари - неупорядоченные коллекции, порядок, в котором идут элементы, никак не гарантируется.

Но можно ли быть уверенным, что наборы `dict.keys()` и `dict.values()` будут соответствовать друг другу?

Т.е., грубо говоря, что `d[list(d.keys())[i]] == list(d.values())[i]` для любого `i < len(d)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order

Comment: Еще бы перевел кто-нибудь...

Comment: перевод простой: все эти методы не ломают словарь, поэтому и порядок остается тот же везде и всегда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если словарь не модифицировался, то да, можно быть уверенным.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Answer (score 0):

есть d.items(), который возвращает кортежи ключ-значение